# How to update the field names automatically in the chart with the change in source table

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI application, where I need to automate the application in such a way that whenever any of the used field name is updated/changed in the source, the same will be updated automatically in the chart objects. E.g. now a bar chart has a field called `Rgn`, the same is there in the source table as well. But tomorrow `Rgn` will be updated to `Region`. Then the same should be reflected in my charts automatically in the next refresh.

I have added the below code in the Advanced editor of the table where the fields exist. After this whenever I am changing anything in the source, the same is getting updated automatically in the tables/data model. But the charts are not reflecting the updated field names. Instead showing error as the earlier field name couldn't be found out by the chart.

```
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",Table.ToRows(Table1))
in 
#"Renamed Columns"
```

The expected result is if the `Rgn` will be updated to `Region` in the source table, the same should be reflected in the charts as well, wherever `Rgn` has been used, e.g in a Table or Slicers.

I have achieved the same in QlikView, but unable to get it done in Power BI.

Thanks a ton in advance!

Regards,

SKD

Comment: When you rename a column through the query editor, PowerBI is clever enough to push that name change through all references.  Unfortunately, I do not believe this is the case in an automated change as you describe above.  The query's column names are changed, but the visuals are still looking for the original name and they break.  I would submit this as a bug ("send a frown") and hopefully it will be improved someday soon.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerBI, fields are tightly linked to the visuals. Whenever DB field name changes then PowerBI will not be able to map the new field with old field automatically.

One simple solution for this scenario would be to use alias in the SELECT statement which is pulling data. For ex. SELECT RGN as Region FROM Geography. 
This way whenever DB field name changes, you'll just need to update the query and Field name within PowerBI dataset remains unchanged.